# deserialization java dat file in jar

Tags: java, jar, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize a .dat file from my resource folder, which works fine. But once I export the project to a jar it gives me a NullPointerException.
Any ideas? Heres the code:

```
String filename = "players.dat";
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(this.getClass().getResource("players.dat").getFile()));
    players = (HashSet<InvolvedPlayer>) ois.readObject();
    System.out.println("Loaded "+players.size());
```

Any help appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Try adding a leading `/` to the path, `/players.dat`

Comment: Also it's probably easier to use
    new ObjectInputStream(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(filename));

Comment: @imps Thank you that worked, but now the same problem persists for writing the players:String filename = "/players.dat";
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(this.getClass().getResource("/players.dat").getFile()));
        oos.writeObject(players);

Comment: What do you mean by the problem persists?

Can you please update the question with your new information and post the NullPointerException to tell us on which line it happens.
Also you can probably use a debugger to help you & tell you which reference is null.